# widget icon sizes for mdpi hdpi xhdpi 2x2 4x4

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

Hi I have to add the Icon which shows the widget description in the Widgets List
There are a few questions

```
a) What is the size of the icon for 2x2 widget and 4x4 widget
b) Do i have to create different icon for mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi 
c) what is the difference between android:icon in reciever and android:previewImage (in xml)
```

Thanks

Comment: did U gothru this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData

Comment: it doesnt say about icon sizes on hdpi / xhdpi devices

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about widget size

always you need to use mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi drawables

so you dpi size will look like

```
 MDPI 32 x 32 px
 HDPI 48 x 48 px
 XHDPI 64 x 64 px
```

This grid can vary by device; for example, many handsets offer a 4x4 grid, and tablets can offer a larger, 8x7 grid. When your widget is added, it will be stretched to occupy the minimum number of cells, horizontally and vertically, required to satisfy its minWidth and minHeight constraints.

[App Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size)

Comment: I am talking about Icons/preview Image for this screen http://blog.stylingandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/widget-selector.png